How to run react app as SSR in spring boot
I have a SPA built using react app and like many other post realized its not the best for SEO because meta tags is the same for all my pages. I have used react helmet and prerender.io to cache the pages but it hasn't helped with ranking much. This makes me believe it would be better to switch and use SSR.
My code runs as a monolith serving the react app via spring boot server configured in maven to create static files and serve it. Given this architecture, I am looking for recommendation on best approach to switch to use SSR.
I have read NextJS is a framework and many have suggested to use that but given I dont have a node server I dont think without full re architecture i can run it. I read about next export but it looks it does not support SSR. What are my options now?
